# How to create a partitioned table with Peewee?

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

When defining my data model with peewee, how can I make a table partitioned by a given field? I’m interested in partitioning a table by a date column, for example, by month of the year.

I see in Peewee’s documentation that I can add custom constraints as part of the Meta part of the data model, how can I then add then partitioning command which would go at the end of the table creation DDL?

Is there a way to do it post schema creation? This would also be a way to go …

Comment: You're going to probably have to write a deal of SQL explicitly in order to achieve this, as we don't have any specific support for partitioning. You can use `Model.Meta.table_settings` to specify partition settings but in all honesty it's probably easier to just write a SQL script and then declare your models dynamically for the partitions you create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some code in my scrap directory that may help you - here I've got a document table that is partitioned into docs that are reviewed/un-reviewed (based on the "is_reviewed" column):

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase('parttest')

class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Document(Base):
    # I believe it is necessary to do it this way vs using SERIAL.
    id = IntegerField(sequence='document_id_seq', index=True)
    name = CharField()
    is_reviewed = BooleanField()
    class Meta:                               
        table_settings = 'PARTITION BY LIST (is_reviewed)'                               


# Doc subclasses for accessing partitions directly.                                      
class DocumentReviewed(Document):
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'document_reviewed'

class DocumentUnreviewed(Document):
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'document_unreviewed'


db.create_tables([Document])

# Create the partitions.
db.execute_sql('create table document_reviewed partition of document '                   
               'for values in (true)')
db.execute_sql('create table document_unreviewed partition of document '                 
               'for values in (false)')
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I can work out a solution to my problem based on this.